# Google maps open infowindow on load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I am trying to have my google mapps infowidnow open on load of the page. I have been trying to work out how to do this, to no avail. I was wondering if anyone could have a look and push me in the right direction?

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.855475, -1.605927);
    var settings = {
        zoom: 16,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"></h1>' +
        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
        '<p></p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
    var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(53.855475, -1.605927);
    var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: companyPos,
        map: map,
        title: "Some title"

    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(companyMarker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, companyMarker);
    });

}
```

Comment: Hi Ellie, How would initialize ever get called? I don't see any event handlers or jQuery $(document).ready(function(){};

Comment: hi @nickgowdy thanks, i have figured it out. i needed to add infowindow.open(map,marker); below my .click function!

Comment: or google.maps.event.trigger(companyMarker,'click');